# accessing JS object's member or method, from within the same object

Tags: javascript, object, methods, this, member

i have the following script, in which i am trying to create a config object for an application :

```
  var myConfig = {
  localDBAllowed: function () {
      return window.openDatabase;
  },
  MessageBox: function (message, title) {
      if (navigator.notification) {
          navigator.notification.alert(message, null, title, 'OK');
      } else {
          alert(message);
      }
  },
  initializeDb: function(){
      if (localDBAllowed) {
          messageBox('local db allowed', '');
      } else {
          messageBox('local db not allowed', '');
      }
  }
  };
  myConfig .initializeDb();
```

the error i get is that localDBAllowed not defined.. from the line : `if (localDBAllowed) {`

my question is how to access an object's member / method from within the sane object.
i tried using this keyword with no success as below:

```
 if (this.localDBAllowed) {
            messageBox('local db allowed', '');
```

Comment: When I make the change you tried (changing the condition to `this.localDBAllowed`) the code works and the condition is executed. Are you perhaps now getting a different error?

Comment: Also note that Javascript is case-sensitive, so your calls to `messageBox(...)` should be `this.MessageBox(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
this.localDBAllowed
```

will not return any values, try

```
this.localDBAllowed()
```

should do the trick

Comment: you need to execute the function, or ```this.localDBAllowed``` will always be true, because you're just testing a function.

Answer (score 0):

*This* worked for me. (Pun intended)

```
var myConfig = {
  localDBAllowed: function () {
      return window.openDatabase;
  },
  messageBox: function (message, title) {
      if (navigator.notification) {
          navigator.notification.alert(message, null, title, 'OK');
      } else {
          alert(message);
      }
  },
  initializeDb: function (){
      if (this.localDBAllowed) {
          this.messageBox('local db allowed', '');
      } else {
          this.messageBox('local db not allowed', '');
      }
  }
};

myConfig .initializeDb();
```

All I did was add the `this` identifier to the areas where functions or variables were called within the object.